# how to configure my gmail id godaddy outbound setting?

Tags: php, email

I need to configure my `gmail id` in my application it can be hosted in GODADDY hosting porvider.

it is showing below error

> Error:SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Share your email code

Comment: where it can be located??

Comment: have you written code for sending email?

Comment: no..I am using Application only

Answer (score 1):

Some persons are Discourage Others. They are thinking about Genius.

The Answer is

SMTP config

Host : localhost
port : 25
Authentication : false